# Dual boot Windows 10 with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

On my hard drive, I have a partition which contains the factory-settings Windows 10 OS and the few files and programs it comes with. I created a partition using most of the spare space and cloned my old (now external) windows 10 hard drive's C drive into this partition. I have tested that I can boot from the external hard drive but now I want to boot the computer from this internal partition which I have made.

Solutions that I have seen often rely on a dual-boot system having two distinct operating systems, and the instructions lead to a menu that asks what operating system the user would like to run, as opposed to which drive/partition to boot from.

EDIT: I have got to a point where I can choose where to boot from but the main problem, I realise, is that it is not recognising my partition as bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't remember the exact steps I took to make this work, I was successful in dual booting Windows 10 and Windows 10 together.

1) Go into BIOS settings (If you don't know how, it's an easy look up that can be slightly different depending on what computer you have) and change the boot order to boot from a USB first.

2) Download and ISO for Windows 10 (Yeah I know, downloading :(... But its not a program!) and burn it to your USB.

3) Reboot your computer with the USB plugged in. You should get a window that pops up asking you whether or not you want to restore your computer or install windows or whatever (I'm not 100% sure).

4) If you want to install a clean copy of Windows 10 to dual boot, the options will be clear. It will ask you which partition etc. However, it seems that you already have a copy there so if you go into repair settings instead (again I'm sorry I'm going off of memory. I don't know exactly what it is), you should be able to "repair" your partition that you copied it onto.

5) Whenever you reboot your computer, the menu should pop up asking you if you want to boot "Windows 10" or "Windows 10". Because of this confusion, I recommend naming your partitions which is a whole other question all together that is fairly easy to handle.

I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: I have followed the instructions to a point where it gives me a list of places to boot from, but in the list of places to boot from in the hard drive, it only says 'Windows 10' once. There are no other options. I think that (As I have encountered quite a few other times) when it gives me a list of things to choose from, it is clear thaqt it is giving me a list of bootable partitions, but it is not recognising my partition as a bootable partition. I am just going to edit the question to include this.

Comment: Is it possible that I should be selecting install instead of repair? Would that wipe that partition?

Comment: I'm at school rn so I can't really check, but when I get home I'll use a USB to try and recreate your situation. If you select install, there may be an option to keep your files. I'm pretty sure there was that option when I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10.

Comment: There was an option for this, which I selected and it told me I could only perform the operation by launching the computer normally, and then manually activating the file on the USB. I got to this point, I selected that yes I would like to keep settings, files and applications, but the next arrow had the word install on it - it didn't look like it was going to give me the option to select which partition to install it on. should I click install anyway, as it probably won't do much harm, or should I turn to another approach?

Comment: For some reason I could boot from the external drive but not the internal partition so (after testing that the USB ISO stuff works on it) I will wipe the internal partition and try copying it over again.

Comment: Still no luck. I think I will just have to use the external hard drive for now, and maybe later buy a 1 terabyte SD card (as my computer has an SD card slot where it is very unlikely to fall out). If I can figure out how, I will close off the question as it is no longer really accurate.